# Transferring equations from Word Equation Editor to StackExchange

Tags: support, markdown, editor

How do I enter equations produced by Word Equation Editor into StackExchange and have them appear as Professional Format equations? When I try by copying from Word and pasting in StackExchange, they appear in Linear Format instead of Professional Format.

Comment: The editor used by Stack Exchange is not supporting any kind of reach format, only markdown so I don't think this is possible.